# How to avoid the display of the 2 first line from a linux command output?

Tags: linux, shell, awk, sed, ash

I have a program that displays many line in the output

How I can make it display the all output except the first 2 lines?

Comment: 11.5 reputation and such a question.  Did you attempt to search at all?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

easily using tail command:

```
tail -n+3
```

Answer (score 2):

You could use `awk`

```
awk 'NR>2' file
```

Answer (score 2):

In order to complete the triplet,

```
sed '1,2d' file
```